# AppPackagesApi not available in the Autodesk.Forge namespace

Tags: autodesk-forge

When I try to reference AppPackagesApi in my application, i am unable to refer it. There is class file for ActivityAPi and AppPackagesApi

Answer (score 0):

Use the forge-api-dotnet-designautomation latest SDK available on NUGET.
The source is here https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-design.automation/blob/790c93633efdf0e865ddb597c13c39863ed14a1c/src/Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation/ApiClient.gen.cs#L32

AppPackagesApi is old name now it is deprecated with Design Automation V2, please use Design Automation V3.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation